# picking up a color from a predefined set of colors in layout file

Tags: android

I'm creating a ListFragment that displays a set of users. For each user is displayed as a TextView with his id on it. I used a style for each text view to display text colors backgroud colors etc.

```
<style name="baseListItemTextView">
    <item name="android:background">?????</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_color</item>
</style>
```

I would like to set each item with different color **android:background**, it could be a total random color or round robin for a set of colors - without any java code(I know one way is to use a customized adaptor and override the getView() method though). Is it possible to do so?